# TYPO3 GeneralUtility Class 0; not found (own generic extension)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

After creating my own Extension with the ExtensionBuilder-Package and activating it, I created a repository for the data and set the Storage-PID in the Template-Constants.

Then I created a new page containing the extension (with default values) and on viewing the page the following error appears and the page does not show:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Class '0;' not found | Error thrown in file /var/www/html/typo3Insy/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
```

*For the setup I used the TYPO3 version 9.5.23 and have not migrated from a previous one.*

Comment: There was never a TYPO3 version 3.9 (and if yes, it would be roughly 15 years old).

Comment: @PeterKraume sry for the mistake - it is now corrected

Comment: Do you use composer and if so did you add the class to autoload psr-4 section? Did you include typoscript templates. You give so little info that we can only guess

Comment: @Jack70 thanks for telling me that there is too little info. I am using composer without specifically adding autoloaders to the composer.json file but have so far experienced no other errors - do I need to add the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jack70 I found out, that an autoloader needs to be supplied for my own extension in the composer.json-File of the TYPO3-installation itself.

From the composer.json-File of the created extension itself, you can extract the vendor name and the site package. Make sure the case matches when supplying it to the autoloader-section:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyVendor\\MySitePackage\\": "pathToTheClassesDirectoryOfYourExtension"
        }
    }
```

After that you can simply run `composer dump-autoload` and this error will be fixed (without restarting the webserver).

I found out about this here: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1289386765